# Using React Router with CDN and without webpack or browserify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requirejs, react-router, cdn

**Resume**: I need to run React Router without wepback or similar tools. Directly from CDN links, but I'm stuck with some require.js error.

---

I'm starting to build my first App with React and I'm struggling with React Router.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>

    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-router@2.4.0/umd/ReactRouter.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel" src="assets/scripts/03_templates/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>
```

JS:

```
var { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory, IndexLink, Link, browserHistory } = ReactRouter;

//some classes 

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Window}>
            <IndexRoute component={InitialPage}/>
            <Route path="register" component={Register} />
            <Route path="search" component={Search} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById("container"));
```

Everything is running fine but i get this on console:

> react.js:3639 Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes
>   validation function for the `getComponent` prop on `IndexRoute`. This
>   is deprecated and will not work in production with the next major
>   version. You may be seeing this warning due to a third-party PropTypes
>   library.

So, I suppose my react Router is a old version. I changed the link to

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.0.0-0/react-router.js"></script>
```

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components).

I search about it and it seems the problem is on line 1. So I changed this:

```
var { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory, IndexLink, Link, browserHistory } = ReactRouter;
```

To this:

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory, IndexLink, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
```

And now I have this problem:

> app.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

I searched for require.js, tried some stuff but nothing fixed my problem. What am I missing? I need to run this without webpack or similars tools.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this on top of your javascript:

```
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;
```

and remove the `import` statements.

I'm currently using this react-router package: `https://unpkg.com/react-router@3.0.0/umd/ReactRouter.js`

EDIT:

Here's an example at CodePen: http://codepen.io/lsmoura/pen/pNPOzp -- it uses no import statements.

Comment: i tried something similar with 4.0.0 and didn't work. so easy no with 3.0.0 thank you so much!

Answer (score 20):

for react route v4.0,please read [react-router package](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages)
add two js link on your page:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```

in js code you can use :

```
const Router = window.ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;
const Route =  window.ReactRouterDOM.Route;
const Link =  window.ReactRouterDOM.Link;
const Prompt =  window.ReactRouterDOM.Prompt;
const Switch = window.ReactRouterDOM.Switch;
const Redirect = window.ReactRouterDOM.Redirect;
```

also,can  use

```
console.log(window.ReactRouterDOM);
```

to out put all object like:

[ReactRouteDOM Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmGD3.png)

Comment: You might want to also add
`const NavLink =  window.ReactRouterDOM.NavLink;`
for nested routing.
Here's a [React Router V4 Nested Routing example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/schafeld/pen/yzvZPj?editors=1010)

Comment: Saved me an hour of debugging and digging. Thanks!

Comment: Thank Youu this actually solve it, so that how you properly import react-router through CDN

Comment: Do we even need the <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router/umd/react-router.min.js"></script> ??? I've tried removing 'react-router.min.js' cdn an only import 'react-router-dom.min.js' and everything still works just fine..

Answer (score 12):

Here's a minimal example of how this can be accomplished:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react@16.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script type='text/babel'>
      const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link,
            Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;

      const App = props => (
        <ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">TO HOME</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/a">TO A</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/b">TO B</Link></li>
          </ul>

          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/a" component={A} />
          <Route path="/b" component={B} />
        </ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
      )

      const Home = props => <h1>HOME</h1>
      const A = props => <h1>A</h1>
      const B = props => <h1>B</h1>

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way you can skip adding react-router.min.js script in the head section
because react-router-dom.min.js is self-sufficient