# How to use React Router on pure HTML like React on browser

Tags: reactjs, react-router, cdn

Is there any way to use React Router on pure HTML like React on the browser?

Example:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking. Do the [react router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) not answer your question?

Comment: No It didn't answer me.

Comment: Oh, you mean getting the library with a script tag. Here's one link: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/5.0.1/react-router.min.js

Comment: Can you give me some examples of it?

Comment: If you are already getting React from a cdn, you can get React Router by using that link as the `src` attribute of a `<script/>` tag, just like you are with React.

Comment: I mean exmaples of how to use react-router

Comment: Please see the docs for usage examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router is beneficial for React [Single Page Apps](https://medium.com/@NeotericEU/single-page-application-vs-multiple-page-application-2591588efe58). Using it in pure HTML files isn't necessary. Here's a nice summary of [React Router's purpose](https://medium.com/@marcellamaki/a-brief-overview-of-react-router-and-client-side-routing-70eb420e8cde).

> React Router, and dynamic, client-side routing, allows us to build a single-page web application with navigation without the page refreshing as the user navigates. React Router uses component structure to call components, which display the appropriate information.

The code example you shared hints at interest in using React from [CDN](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/what-is-a-cdn/) rather than [installing the library](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/quick-start) in your project. If that's the case, it may help to review the post [Using React Router with CDN and without webpack or browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764596/using-react-router-with-cdn-and-without-webpack-or-browserify).