# React set Route in Component function without Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my react application, When I click on 'Add New Tab', I call 'addNewproject' function.

```
<button onClick={() => this.addNewproject() }>Add New Tab</button>
```

In 'addNewproject' function new Tab get added in DB. What I require is to set my route to:

"?TabId=newTabID"

```
addNewproject = () => {
 //axios post happens and we get new Tabid just created in DB.
var newTabID= 623 //id from DB for ex.

//set here either like "?TabId=newTabID" and add to ROUTE
}

render() {
var newTabID = this.state.newTabId;
//OR add here "?TabId=newTabID" and add to ROUTE
}
```

How can I add it to the URL? I referred few articles but they all said to use a component that is making me confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `history` object that is passed as prop to components wrapped in `Route` in `react-router`.

[Documentation is available here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md).

After adding new project user should be redirected by history using `push` or `replace` methods, like that:

```
history.push(`${history.location.pathname}?TabId=${newTabID}`)
```

Comment: Thanks.
how can I use history with CDN?
I have used 

<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router@5.0.0/umd/react-router.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js'></script>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class RouteComp extends Component {
  navigate = () => {
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/pathname',
      search: '?TabId=`${this.state.newTabId}'
    })
  }

  render () {
    <button onClick={this.navigate}>Navigate</button>
  }
}

export default withRouter(RouteComp);
```

Comment: Can you please convert it into code used when UMD script tags are used.
<script src='unpkg.com/react-router@5.0.0/umd/…> <script src='unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/…>


I am getting "history.push is not a function" error.

Comment: I am using non CRA environement, just using script tags.So not sure how to use "export default withRouter(RouteComp);"

I have done "var browserHistory = window.ReactRouterDOM.browserHistory;" at top.

and in 'addNewproject' function I am using "history.push("URL_WITH_NEW_TABID")

Comment: I am getting "history.push is not a function" error

Comment: @dhiraj00 would you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764596/using-react-router-with-cdn-and-without-webpack-or-browserify

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it using Redirect. 
redirectURL is set in addNewProject function.

{redirectURL !== '' && 
          <ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter>
            <Redirect to={redirectURL} />
          </ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter>
        }