# How to redirect page without refreshing on react added to a website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am following the steps here in https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html,
I used the script tags for adding react js.
I also running
`npx babel --watch src/jsx/ --out-dir src/ui/js --presets react-app/prod` to be able to use JSX syntax.

I am currently using `window.location.href` to redirect but the page is refreshing.

So I tried to use ReactRouter by `<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js'></script>` but ReactRouterDOM.Link not found.

How to redirect page without refreshing on react added to a website?

Comment: Use react router with hook `useHistory` something like: `const history = useHistory();` and then `history.push('your/route')` [React Router Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

Comment: Try as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56009907/2873538). Make sure to include React, React DOM and React Router DOM, (and babel if you are using) cdns.

Comment: I used ReactRouter but I am receiving Invalid hook call error.

Answer (score 0):

If I added this script tag on html page,
`<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js'></script>`

I can now access these objects,

```
const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
const Switch = ReactRouterDOM.Switch;
const Router = ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;
```