# Access BrowserRouter without JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to get at a BrowserRouter without using JSX.  So far, everything I've done with other components has worked, but for some reason this one doesn't.  Output shows that BrowserRouter is not defined.  There must be something really simple that I'm missing.  Can anyone spot it?  Thanks!

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@6.6.1/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            console.log(React);
            console.log(ReactDOM);
            console.log(React.StrictMode);
            console.log(BrowserRouter);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe it would be something like `ReactRouterDom.BroswerRouter`. Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764596/using-react-router-with-cdn-and-without-webpack-or-browserify

Comment: So far, it looks like ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter works.  Now Routes and Route are complaining.  They aren't found in the same place.  Any idea?

Comment: ReactRouter.Route, ReactRouter.Routes after fetching the right script.

Comment: That was going to be my only thought, that those components were exported from `react-router`.... even though `react-router-dom` is supposed to re-export all of `react-router` (*AFAIK*). I guess it's different in the umd world.